# Trouble using GET for a json file in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, server

I'm new to REST api's and javascript in general and I'm having trouble using GET to retrieve a json file and display it in a browser. I'm only running my api as a localhost for now. I can get my server running but just can't get my json file to display. Below is my code, I have tried different things with the responce but have had no luck with getting it to work. Everything I've tried with it has displayed errors. Both this file and the json file are in the same folder. If someone knows what I need to put for instead of the //responce() it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.port || 3000;

app.listen(port, function(){
    var datetime = new Date();
    var message = "Server running on Port:- " + port + " Started at :- " + 
datetime;
    console.log(message);   
});

app.get("/userget", function(request, responce){
    var fs = require('fs');
    var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('database.json', 'utf8'));
    //responce()
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your javascript object, try:

res.status(200).json({
        your_javascript_object
      });

Comment: I'm glad to help you out:)

Answer (score 0):

Put this instead for your /userget route.

````
```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
var fs = require('fs');
res.send(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('database.json', 'utf8')));
```
````